# ETIMEDOUT on NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm getting an ETIMEDOUT exception on NPM when trying to install date-fns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrYlr.png)

I've set the fetch-retry-maxtimeout to 6000000 and the fetch-retry-mintimeout to 1000000.

Node Version 16.

I've tried to do a cache clean force. Tried restarting my PC. Tried using another internet source.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Don't post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Post the actual text.